# How to get the material data of specific IfcElement

Tags: c#, linq, ifc, bim, xbim

In the basic operations in the xbim examples https://docs.xbim.net/examples/basic-model-operations.html, it shows how to retrieve the single value properties of a specific IfcElement. Based on this I've tried to get the material data.

I've written the following:

```
var id = "3NBPkknun6EuV9fpeE6rFh";

var theWall = model.Instances.FirstOrDefault<IIfcElement>(d => d.GlobalId == id);

var materials = theWall.HasAssociations
                        .Where(r => r.RelatingMaterial is IIfcMaterialProfileSet)
                        .SelectMany(r=> ((IIfcMaterialProfileSet)r.RelatingMaterial).MaterialProfiles)
                        .OfType<IIfcMaterialProfile>();
```

It gives me this error:

> 'IIfcRelAssociates' does not contain a definition for
>   'RelatingMaterial' and no accessible extension method
>   'RelatingMaterial' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IIfcRelAssociates' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

I understand that I have to use the IfcRelAssociatesMaterial, but I can't figure how.
How can I retrieve the material information?

Comment: Can you locate the model?  If you right click model and then select "go to definition" you will find the model and the properties

Comment: Thank you @jdweng ,I found that the model doesn't have the IfcRelAssociatesMaterial property, but it has a Material property. It didn't solved my problem, but it sure helped.

Comment: The model may need to be refreshed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIfcObjectDefinition's `HasAssociations` returns a set of `IIfcRelAssociates` but you want just the derived type `IIfcRelAssociatesMaterial` which has the `RelatingMaterial` property. See https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/RELEASE/IFC4/ADD2/HTML/schema/ifcproductextension/lexical/ifcrelassociatesmaterial.htm

So, it's just a matter of adding `.OfType<IIfcRelAssociatesMaterial>` to constrain the query to Material associations. i.e.

```cs
var materials = theWall.HasAssociations.OfType<IIfcRelAssociatesMaterial>() 
// rest of the query
```